# Word that describes the thing which has an aspect or facet

Tags: single-word-requests

Basically, is there a relationship words/phrase for "that which can have aspects"?

If I have an aspect/facet "A", that belongs to thing "B".  A is an Aspect, and B is a `<noun>`

Something like "Aspectee", but a real word.

Sample sentence: "Please tell me the 'Aspectee' of the aspect 'A'?"

Edit: To clarify:  If "A is an `Aspect` of B", then "B is a(n) `<?>` of A"

Comment: a ***multi-faceted*** object.

Comment: @KannE, thing or object, but to make those work in the sample sentence would be awkward.  To put this another way "A is an Aspect of B", and "B is a <...> of A"

Comment: an example of...   Furry is an aspect of a dog.  A dog is an example of [something] furry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you go back to Plato, you can consider *Form* to be your *aspect* or *facet* - the abstracted ‘thing’ - and *Matter* to be its concrete equivalent.

> The problem of universals – how can one thing in general be many things in particular – was solved by presuming that Form was a distinct singular thing but caused plural representations of itself in particular objects.
>
> ...
>
> The theory of matter and form (today's hylomorphism) started with Plato and possibly germinal in some of the presocratic writings. The forms were considered as being "in" something else, which Plato called nature (physis). The latter seemed as carved "wood", ὕλη (hyle) in Greek, corresponding to materia in Latin, from which the English word "matter" is derived, shaped by receiving (or exchanging) forms.
>
> [- Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_forms)

In your example, you could say:

- If "A is an Aspect of B", then "B is a *materialisation* of A".

To use [Jim’s](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/483693/word-that-describes-the-thing-which-has-an-aspect-or-facet/483728#comment1167662_483693) example: if *furriness* is an aspect of *dog*, then *dog* is a materialisation of *furriness*.

Alternatively, if you use the earlier portion of the quote above, taking the *aspect* as the “one thing in general”, then each of the “many things in particular” can be called an *instance*:

> If "A is an Aspect of B", then "B is a *instance* of A".

For example, the *generic table* is an aspect of an *IKEA table*, and an *IKEA table* is an instance of the *generic table*.

Comment: Materialization and Instance both fit what I need. Instance is a bit better, so that's what I ended up going with.  Thanks for your help!